# pub get failed ( depends on both pay ^1.0.8 and flutter_html ^2.2.1, version solving failed)

Tags: flutter, get, flutter-dependencies

Flutter 3.0 Give Error While Implementing both Flutter_html and pay In same project

Here is depency level i have used in my package:

```
pay: ^1.0.8
flutter_html: ^2.2.1
```

> Error : Because flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 depends on flutter_svg >=0.22.0 <1.0.0 and pay_android >=1.0.6 depends on flutter_svg ^1.0.0, flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 is incompatible with pay_android >=1.0.6.
> And because pay >=1.0.7 depends on pay_android ^1.0.6, flutter_html >=2.0.0-nullsafety.1 <3.0.0-alpha.1 is incompatible with pay >=1.0.7.
> So, because project_name depends on both pay ^1.0.8 and flutter_html ^2.2.1, version solving failed.
> pub finished with exit code 1

Comment: try by changing the version of your packages will resolve the issue. Try different version until both packages become compatible.

Comment: Yes already done that but didn't find proper match.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hopefully today I re-search the package and found a temporary solution for this issue. you can use the prerelease version of the package it will remove the error.

```
flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.3
```

you can find it after this line in pub.dev

> Published 33 days ago• verified publisher iconsub6resources.comNull safety• Latest: 2.2.1 / ***Prerelease: 3.0.0-alpha.3***

Comment: yes, this is worked for me. My current flutter version is 3.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those that want to use the 2.x.x version. The problem is the max flutter_svg version restriction, I have forked the project and updated the restriction.

```
-  flutter_svg: '>=0.22.0 <1.0.0'
+  flutter_svg: '>=0.22.0 <2.0.0'
```

You can add this package from my fork or create your own. To add my fork use this code in your pubspec.yaml

```
  flutter_html:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/AlmisSolutions/flutter_html.git
      ref: main_lts
```